# On the proof that, if $(xy)^2=(yx)^2$ for all $x$ and $y$ in a group, then $xy^2=y^2x$ for all $x$ and $y$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let G be a group and $(xy)^2=(yx)^2$ for all $x, y ∈ G$. Show that $xy^2=y^2x$ for all $x, y ∈ G$.

I understand the solution for this question but I have seen some people solve it in this way:

Choose $y = x^{-1}y$ and substitute in for $y$

$$xx^{−1}yxx^{−1}y=x^{−1}yxx^{−1}yx⟹y^2=x^{−1}y^2x⟹xy^2=y^2x$$

My issue with this solution is that we're assuming under multiplication closure for any arbitrary element $y ∈ G$, we have $y = x^{-1}y$ for all $x ∈ G$. This seems incorrect. Can anyone explain why I may be wrong about this?

Comment: "under multiplication closure for any arbitrary element $y ∈ G$, we have $y = x^{-1}y$ for all $x ∈ G$" Even after having scratched my head for a moment over this sentence, I fail to understand what it could mean.

Comment: We're talking about groups and they can have different operations, in this case it is multiplication.

Comment: Off-topic. In any group, $y=x^{-1}y$ iff $x=e$... and this is obviously not what you mean when you write "Choose $y = x^{-1}y$".

Comment: This is not my solution, my confusion was what you just described, that $x$ can only be the identity element here. But supposedly $y$ on the LHS is not the same as the one on the RHS. I mention this in my response to the answer below.

Comment: So, no pending question?

Comment: that would be correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $G$ is a group, every $x \in G$ has an inverse $x^{-1}\in G$. Since $G$ is closed under multiplication, for any $y\in G$ you have that $x^{-1}y \in G$.

Comment: I understand that $x^{-1}y ∈ G$ but why does it equal to $y$ itself? Wouldn't it be more appropriate to use another variable $u$ instead?

Comment: A, ok I see your confusion. Yes, actually in $y=x^{-1}y$, the y on the LHS is not the same as $y$ on the RHS. He avoids using $u$ to reduce notation, but he could have done it yes. The meaning is that he has a formula that holds for any $y \in G$ so also for $x^{-1}y$ which is an element of $G$. It would be more appropriate to write: "For $x^{-1}y$, which is an element of $G$, the given formula gives.." or something like that.